# Can touching 2 live wires trip breaker?

Tags: protection

I have two questions. I couldn't find it in google or archives.

First. When you accidentally touch both line and neutral or line to line with your fingers or different parts of your body (for example, fingers to line, toe to neutral or another line), what is the minimum amperage of the circuit breaker before it can trip?  For example, if you have a 60 ampere circuit breaker.. would it trip when you accidentally touch line and neutral, or line to line?

Second. If line and neutral touch themselves, what is the maximum breaker amperage when it can still trip. Like if the breaker rating is 500 Ampere.. it may no longer trip when the line and neutral touch would it. I want to know if specifically 60 Ampere breaker can trip if line to neutral or line to line shorts or touches.

Answer (score 7):

In general, circuit breakers provide protection from overloads and short circuits.  Their primary purpose is to protect the wiring - overloaded wiring will overheat, break down insulation, and eventually start a fire.

They are designed to trip immediately on short circuit, when you have line to line or line to neutral contact.  With a short circuit, you have extremely high current.

They are not designed to trip immediately on overload at their nominal protection rating;  in other words, your 60 amp breaker won't trip immediately under a 61 amp load.  There is a "trip curve" for the breaker, which describes how long it takes to trip on overload - longer / slower for a slight overload, shorter / faster for a more dramatic overload.

When accidental contact causes current to flow through your body, your body's resistance is high enough that the current is usually quite small;  it only takes tiny currents to cause injury or death.  This won't trip a regular breaker - it isn't a short circuit or an overload.  Regular circuit breakers are not designed to trip for safety.

Note that faults that travel through ground are also usually through high enough ground resistance that small currents flow, not enough to trip a breaker.  When an equipment grounding system is in place, it will provide a low resistance path for many faults, allowing enough current to flow to quickly trip the breaker and "clear the fault."

GFCI / GFI / RCD circuit breakers have another means of tripping.  A GFCI device monitors for the current on each of the two or three wires to see if there's any current going out on one wire that isn't returning on the others, which means there must be current flowing through ground, which could be a person receiving a shock.  There are different types of GFCI, but common US class A GFCI trips at only 4-6 milliamps of current, low enough to prevent injury.  Other types have higher trip levels.

Note that a GFCI only protects against accidental contact that causes a ground fault;  under some circumstances you can still receive a shock from a GFCI.  For example, if you are wearing rubber soled shoes on a dry wooden floor and are making no ground contact, and you grabbed a bare neutral with one hand then a bare line conductor with the other, there would likely be no current flowing through the ground, and the GFCI would not trip.

Comment: I bought a 60 Ampere GFCI 2-pole breaker just to power an oven, and I couldn't return it.  I should have bought the 30 Ampere version. I was supposed to connect it in series with existing 30 Ampere normal breaker.. but because I couldn't connect the plug in type without a panel.. and I ordered a 6 branches plug-in panel. I can no longer connect it to the existing 30 Ampere in series but 100 Ampere main. So it's only good for short circuit and GFCI function. But notice even if your load is an oven, your breaker in panel has rating of 20 Ampere which is still over size.. is my 60 Ampere so high?

Comment: @samzun - I am not quite following but this sounds like way more than a comment, why not post another question?

Comment: It would be too complicated... just want to know whether you can use 60 Ampere breaker just to power an oven?  So the protection is only for short circuit and not overload.. isn't it...

Comment: btw.. this is related to your answer.. why is there a warning in my Siemens gfci breaker in the Safety Instructions part that: "To obtain maximum protection against electric shock, electric ranges and clothes dryers whose frames are grounded by connection to the grounded circuit conductor should not be connected to the load circuit of this device." Why?

Comment: @samzun, if I follow, I believe that is referring to the practice of bonding the neutral to the frame of the appliance when connecting these appliances with a three wire cord with no equipment grounding conductor.  Connected that way, the frame of the device can return ground current through the neutral, which would hide the imbalance from the GFCI, preventing it from tripping on a ground fault that creates a high impedance ground fault.  (A dead short / low impedance fault would trip the breaker on overload / short, not GFCI.)

Comment: So in general, the load side of any GFCI breaker can still be connected to any equipments with normal grounding conductor (the 4th wire)?  What does UL says about this.  But doesn't the above "grounded circuit conductor" mean the ground wire itself and not the neutral? Have you heard of any other warnings that equipments with normal grounding shouldn't be connected to 2-pole gfci breaker?

Comment: @samzun - The wiring scheme they are referring to is no longer in common use in the US, although it is very common in older homes and buildings.  But I gather from your remarks it may be in current use in your location.  Very important distinction:  the grounded circuit conductor is the neutral, it carries current under normal conditions, but is bonded to ground, zero volts to ground;  the equipment grounding conductor does not normally carry current, only in case of a fault. (I recommend researching and reading up on this ... I think you'll find it far more helpful than these comments.)

Comment: I'm very familiar with it. I see.. so grounded circuit conductor is term for the neutral, that clear things up. About breaker rating. It's common to have 20 Ampere normal breaker when your load is just 3 Ampere.. for example light loads.. isn't it?

Comment: @Samzun - not unusual at all for a circuit protected by a  20A breaker to have 3A load, but still it's very important that everything be sized to handle the full 20A.

Comment: @batsplatsterson the H-H-N NEMA 10 connection is in extremely common use.  It spreads like a virus onto newer housing stock, because people who move into a newer home change the receptacle to NEMA 10 so it fits their dryer cord, which they presume is unremovable.  Once thus downgraded, no one ever upgrades it back, because they assume NEMA 10 means no ground is available.  So they change the cord.  Appliance stores amplify this by offering to change the plug to suit your socket. The vast majority of Q's here involve 3-wire connections.

Comment: @Samzun **groundED conductor** is a technical word for the neutral wire.  Not to be confused with the **equipment groundING conductor**, which is ground.

Comment: Ok. Say. If I have existing 30A 2-pole breaker.. can I add a 60A GFCI breaker in series to it (let's say I can connect it individually)? Can the 30A still trip like normal? I just need the GFCI  function of the 60A with superior automatic self test.

Comment: @samzun, yes, what you're describing is completely typical - in a panel, the main breaker is in series ahead of all the branch circuits.

Comment: But notice that the main breaker is 30A.. while 60A is connected between 30A and equipment.. so would the 30A trip or would the 60A after it masks it? Again the rating is reverse because I got a 60A GCFI for value and haven't thought of it before.

Comment: @samzun, two breakers in series will operate independently, there is no masking effect.  When you do things outside of the norm, you just have to be very careful you're still observing all the rules, ratings, instructions, listings, etc.  Getting creative with electricity is dangerous enough in a lab, not a good idea in a house....

Comment: I read that before a breaker trips, the temperature of the wire has to be certain value.. so I was just concerned the 60A can shield the heat of the wire to the 30A in the main panel making the 30A unable to trip.

Comment: @samzun - The thermal trip heat is produced by the current flowing inside the breaker.

Comment: Ok. So I can connect my 60A to existing 30A in order to avail of the lower amp breaker at main panel. Please see this thread https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150063/connecting-plug-in-breaker-in-series-to-existing-breaker?noredirect=1#comment248047_150063 maybe you have ideas how to connect plug in breaker to existing load output of another breaker individually... thanks.

Comment: Guys. I just need to know something and I don't want to create a new post since it could be duplicate but not really answered. Have you heard of anyone getting shocked or electrocuted just by bathing assuming the heater is faulty. I mean, can the faulty heater conduct the water to your shower, down your body, and to the floor? Or doesn't this event happen, and why? I'm justifying where to install GFCI in the shower heater.

Answer (score 3):

A breaker will trip when the current through it exceeds its rating. (With a few caveats with regards on how long it takes them to trip).

Breakers also have a voltage rating which tells how high of a voltage they can break reliably. If you exceed that rating the current may continue to arc between the contacts.

*However it only takes a few milliAmps to kill you.* This is way below what breakers will trip at.

**So you cannot rely on them to keep you alive.** Their main purpose is to prevent fires from wires overheating and igniting the structure.

Comment: But in many homes.. if your load is only 5A or 9A or 12.. most use uniform 20A breaker.. not good?  Or consider most of your load off at night and only your 2 Ampere CCTV opened.. the 20A breaker would be 10 times the load. What do you make of this common scenario?

Comment: The breaker rating is the maximum current it will allow through before it breaks. It is perfectly happy letting through less indefinitely.

Comment: In  that case, the use of the oversized breaker is for tripping direct shorts between line to neutral.. or line to ground. I'm just justifying the purchase of 60A breaker instead of 30A. Do you know the maximum amperage of a circuit breaker when it would no longer trip? like 200A for shorted line to neutral?

Comment: In a correct circuit breakers will *always* trip in the presence of a short. The max rating of a breaker is decided by the wires it is protecting. Overrating a breaker risks fires when the wires are overloaded.

Comment: @Ratchet freak home breakers do not trip at there rated value for an overload in fact they may Cary 3x to 5x there rated value and as blatsplaterson explained trip curves for standard breakers are called inverse time breakers if a short the trip or open quickly but if the load on a 60 amp breaker is not a short but for example a motor load the breaker will hold for 10-20 seconds at 120 amps or higher based on the trip curve for that breaker. There are also rules for the maximum size of breakers usually 150% for corded devices a 3 amp load would be listed for 15 amp circuit but can use 20a +BP.

Comment: My home wiring is mostly AWG 12 with current rating of 40A. During a short.. how many quick ampere rise can occur to the 40A wire.. can it reach 1000A in burst..  is it enough to trip a 60A breaker?

Comment: @Samzun what is your plan? If you need high amp pulses there are way to do that without blowing breakers, though I hesitate to suggest them to someone who barely seems to know one end of a wire from another.

Comment: I already bought 2 pcs of 60A breaker I can't return. So if I use it with existing AWG 12 wire (with 40A rating) in my room.. at least it would trip if the lines get shorted, right?

Comment: @Samzun your fire insurance is not going to be happy with you fudging your breakers and wire gauges.

Comment: Just wondering about something. Many suffer electric shock.. how come they are able to remove the fingers or hand from the ac source? isn't it at certain mA, one would get paralyzed? So how come technicians only mostly suffer shock and not electrocution?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a US GFCI breaker, it'll trip within 20ms on excess of 8 milliamps, which may be a memorable experience for you.

A Euro RCD (=GFCI) breaker will trip on excess of 30ma, which can stun and might kill you.

A Euro RCD rated for human protection will trip at around 6ma.

All other breakers, depends who you are.  If you are Colossus from X-Men, you are made of metal and it will trip the breaker.   Deadpool or Claire from Heroes, it will hurt until you let go, *if you even can let go*.  If you are Bruce Banner, it will make you very angry.  Thanos, anyone's guess.  Everyone else, you are dead.  Sorry, Jean Grey.  The person who finds your body is also dead.

Comment: Harper, in the thread "Too small ground wire". You stated "The thermal trip is sized to warm at about the same speed as the wire in the walls, so it trips somewhat before the wire warms enough to be dangerous. That requires matching between breaker and wire size.". What if the wire in the wall is put near ice. Then it won't warm enough.. would this trip the breaker? This confused me for a month. It's as if the breaking tripping depends on the temperture in the wire. Couldn't it be easier to say it trips on current at breaker?

Comment: @samzun it's the best way to make assumptions about the breaker vs. wire temperature.  They don't actually embed thermometers in the wire and have them communicate with the breaker.  You have contrived an edge condition that reduces the method's relevance, but if you go to all that trouble to chill the cable, then yeah, you get to uprate the cable whilst the refrigeration plant is in operation.  I believe there's a derate/uprate table for that in NEC.