# Connecting Plug-In breaker in series to existing breaker

Tags: electrical

I need to connect this to existing normal breaker of 30A.

[image: 1]

I can't use a breaker panel because it would mess up the existing amperage. I just need the GFCI function of the above (especially its superior automatic self-test that isn't available in any 240v 2-pole receptacle). Any idea how to connect some kind of metal interface or adaptor to the plug-in conductor portion? I have to build one since a commercially available adaptor doesn't exist. Then I'd series it with existing 30A breaker load side (which is also 2-pole).

Comment: Your statement "I can't use a breaker panel because it would mess up the existing amperage" doesn't make any sense. Adding a sub-panel to your existing panel shouldn't mess up or change anything about the amperage of the  existing panel. Do not try to build some sort of hokey adapter for that new GFCI breaker - just put in a sub-panel where it belongs. But anyway, why aren't you just replacing the existing 30A breaker with a 30A GFCI?

Comment: Siemens 30A GFCI is much wider than normal. My main panel has 20 normal breakers.. I just need to connect 4 GFCI to 4 existing 30A breakers. If I use a subpanel for each breaker. 4 subpanels can't fit. And I already bought 2 pcs of 60A Siemens GFCI that I can no longer return. So I just want to connect each directly to the 30A output.

Comment: A QF230A is exactly the same size as the QF260A in your photo... But nevertheless to use the GFCI's you have you wouldn't need 4 subpanels, you'd only need 2.

Comment: Even 2 would take up so much space.. i should have ordered 30A gfci but wrongly ordered 60A. Anyway i can buy separate plug in bus bar..cut it to one piece and screw lug to it and connect this to plug in. This wil work..wont it. Anyone has better adaptor suggestion?

Comment: I am voting to close this question since it is not really asking a question and if there was a question there would need to be more detail about the scope and situation.

Comment: Before you close. Can anyone tell me what smallest Siemens panel is compatible with this breaker that is available at amazon or digi-key? is the smallest one a 2 branch? What is the model?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against hacking breakers. It's not uncommon at all to have problems - sometimes serious problems, even a fire - when breakers don't fit properly to the bus in factory made panels.  Even small differences in thickness etc. can make the connection insecure.  If the factory can make mistakes, it's just too risky to mess with on your own.

Siemens makes spa panels and breaker enclosures that would house the 60A breaker alone.  Unfortunately at that point you may be spending more money than you would just scrapping the 60A GFCI and buying the 30A GFCI that you really wanted.  Plus, it's more space, more things to go wrong, etc.

Comment: What if I buy another plug-in breaker and connect the two at the slits.. is there such connector?  And is it true that ac source can enter the load side and exit the line side? How do you tell which plug in can do this and which can't?

Comment: Even if I can exchange it with 30A Siemens GFCI (amazon doesn't take GFCI returns).. It's still too big for my original panel.. so I need subpanel either way. Do you know the exact Siemens panel 2 branch model that is compatible with this breaker model?

Comment: @samzun - http://lmgtfy.com/?q=siemens+qf+circuit+breaker+enclosure

Comment: @samzun https://www.siemens.com/content/dam/internet/siemens-com/ca/home/energy/pdf/ppc-sections/s01-loadcentres.pdf

Comment: Thanks. In my country. 100% of our panels are either generic ones or made at generic panel fabricator. We never used branded panels matched to the breaker. So this is my first time to use this, and one of the first times in my country. Also shipping it all the way to asia would cost twice the breaker price so need to be sure it can fit perfectly.

Comment: @samzun - you know the saying, when in Rome... See if you can get through to Siemens tech support before purchasing to assure compatibility.  If you get a knowledgeable representative they may know the best product for the task.  Siemens support even answers questions on the Home Depot web site.